# Will SSD "Kingston SSDNow UV400" work on ASUS M5A78LM LE motherboard?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

Will SSD "Kingston SSDNow UV400" (120GB) work on ASUS M5A78LM LE motherboard?
Will it be compatible?

> Built-in Controller :  6 x SATA 3Gb/s port(s), blue

**Kingston SSDNow UV400** - https://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/consumer/suv400s3

**ASUS M5A78LM LE** - https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A78LM_LE/specifications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Kingston website about your drive:

> Our SATA III (6Gbit/s) SSDs are tested to be backwards compatible to SATA II (3Gbit/s). They are not designed or tested to be backwards compatible with SATA I ports (1.5Gbit/s).

Certainly seems so without looking too much into it, SATA II on the motherboard, SATA III on the drive.

If the hardware isn't faulty it should work fine although limited to SATA II speeds/performance.

Comment: Worth pointing out that just because they were not tested, does not mean, it will not work.  The SATA standard is backwards compatible, what might make it incompatible, is the SATA chipset being used.